# Why does Rails defaults to SSL in development?

Tags: ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, thin, pow

This thread on github says that [defaults for development not use ssl configuration](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5023) it still forces ssl even in development. Is there a way to avoid this?

Im running Rails 4.0.0

UPDATE

Updated to Rails 4.0.2 - still always redirects to https in development for localhost:3000 and pow (.dev) url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser was caching the https request. So I just closed the browser and restarted.